# How can I disable SELinux in Red Hat?

Tags: security, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm having some issues with shared libraries in a Red Hat installation, for example when I try to run sqlplus:

```
error while loading shared libraries: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied
```

How can I permanently disable SELinux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit /etc/selinux/config and change the SELINUX line to:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

another possible solution is to execute as root:

```
#setup 
  Select "Firewall Configuration"
```

There you can configure the Firewall and SELinux